# Best transmitter to trigger and adjust both AD360 II for Nikon and Yongnuo 568 EX speedlights?

Tags: wireless-flash, triggers, godox

I am a Nikon user and I have some Yongnuo 568EX speedlights. I am considering buying a Godox AD360 II-N flash but I am trying to decide which would be my best bet for a transmitter which could most effectively trigger and control power remotely of both the Godox AD360 and, at the same time, the Yongnuo 568EX flashes, even in TTL mode.

There is a kit on sale which includes the Godox AD360 II N and a Godox X1 transmitter which apparently is ideal for the AD 360. Is there a possibility of benefiting from the CLS Nikon (optical) capability of the Yongnuo flashes and therefore avoid having to buy receivers for each individual Yongnuo flash and control the AD360 and the Yongnuo speedlights with only one transmitter?

Answer (score 2):

No. The X1 triggering system is radio. CLS is optical, and your camera can't send out both at the same time, because the hotshoe and popup can't be operated at the same time and you can't use PC sync if you want TTL/HSS and all the other goodies you bought the AD360 II for.

You can try using a YN-622N on the AD360II, but I've heard there are issues with the HSS and only supersync works via the PC connector. You could try adding a Godox X1R-N receiver to the YN-568EX.

You'd probably be best off replacing the Yongnuos and going for [Godox TT685N speedlights](http://flashhavoc.com/godox-tt685n-ttl-speedlight-released/) that have X1 transreceivers built-in. This way, you're all in the same system, and you never have to worry about bringing along external receivers for your flashes.

This is the main problem with TTL or power-control radio triggering—it typically only works with specific flash/trigger combinations, because every manufacturer wants to lock you into their system.